# Ajax call results in 404

Tags: 7, ajax

I'm porting an applet (tested standalone) to embedd it into a Drupal site.

It includes some Ajax processes, which work fine in the original version.
Once adapted for Drupal, they all result in 404.

Below is a simplified excerpt of how I'm working.

**myModule.module**

```
function myModule_menu() {
  return [
    'myModule-ajax' => [
      'page callback'     => '_myModule_ajax_handle',
      'access arguments'  => ['access content'],
      'type'              => MENU_CALLBACK,
    ],
  ];
}

// ...

function _myModule_ajax_handle() {
  // here is a deliberately simplified return
  return '{"test": "Ajax result sample"}';
}
```

**JS part**

```
(function($) {

// Set common $.ajax properties.
$.ajaxSetup({
  url: 'myModule-ajax',
  //method: 'POST', 
  dataType: 'json',
  error: function(jqXHR, status, error) {
    console.log(status + ': ', error);
  }
});

getSqlObj('Depts'); // -> sqlDepts

// ...

function getSqlObj(objName) {
  $.ajax({
    data: {
      ajax: 'get' + objName
    },
    success: function(response) {
      // ...
    }
  })
}

})(jQuery);
```

With Firefox devtools I can see that the right url was called, in this case:

`myModule-ajax?ajax=getDepts`

but the status is 404, and the returned data is **the fully rendered** current page, with a message replacing the current node content:

> Requested page "/mySite/fr/myModule-ajax?ajax=getDepts" not found

So I wonder not only why I get a 404 status, but also why I get this data returned.

NOTE: among a number of tries with differently expresses urls, I noticed another weirdness: at the time of `url` affectation (in `$.ajaxSetup()` above), `Drupal.settings.basePath` is undefined (in fact, `Drupal.settings` exists but is empty).
In the other hand, it contains all expected data when examined through the console just after the fail.

Comment: Alternatively you can use [drupal_json_output()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_json_output/7.x) instead of returning a json formatted string. Is this ajax suppose to be post or get?

Comment: @DMAC Thanks for your interest to my issue. As commented in the code above, my current return is a (temporary) simplification, for the 1st tests. But I agree that I should use `drupal_json_output()` in the real work. Since you cited it, I'm pretty interested about `POST` vs `GET` (`POST` is what I'll actually need, because some data to send may be of some weight). But adding `method: POST` seems to be ignored: always results in a `GET` in the Drupal context! I didn't understand that, and didn't find more information about that. So if you can share any advice about it, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

A post request is when you are sending information to the server and returning  response data, get is just simply just grabbing data. This is an example of a post AJAX request I have working in Drupal, stripped down. It is assuming data is being passed from the ajax call into PHP then is returned back to JS.

Create your AJAX path with [hook_menu()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7.x) in your custom module

```
function hook_menu(){ 
  $items = array();

  $items['my_ajax_path'] = array(
    'title'             => 'My Ajax path that does stuff',
    'page callback'     => 'myPageCallBack',
    'type'              => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );    

  return $items;
}
```

Create your page callback for your menu defined in hook_menu() in custom module

```
function myPageCallBack(){
 if(isset($_POST['myData'])){
   $postData = $_POST['myData']
   return drupal_json_output($postData);    
 }
}
```

AJAX Call in your custom JS file (location is up to you but i find this is easy to maintain, you can add js to a page using [drupal_add_js](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7.x))

```
function call_AJAX(myVariable){
    jQuery.ajax({
      url: "/my_ajax_path?action=myPageCallBack",
      type: "POST", 
      data: {myData: myVariable},
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data){
            alert(data);
            if(data == ''){
                alert('There was an error processing the form. Please try again later.');
                return;
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error){
                console.log(xhr);
                console.log(xhr.status);
        },
    });     
}
```

I stripped this out of a working example quickly and didn't test it outside of my working environment as i'm actually leaving work right now, but using the above code i can make post ajax requests no issue. Let me know if this works for you!

Comment: Thanks for this answer. But, no offense, it doesn't help much, and it's my bad, because I indeed was too short in the explanation of my issue. In fact I'm pretty used to work with Ajax (both through `GET` or `POST`) _outside of Drupal_. More over, for my first try with Drupal, my real code (not simplified as in my OP) looks pretty like your example. My current issue is that for some reason I'm facing a behaviour that don't match my experience: the unexpected (and unexplained) 404, the fact that I got back a full rendered page. And to have noticed is that specifying `POST` gave me a `GET`!

Comment: Anyway, note: your answer helps me in the sense that it makes me reasonably sure of the way I used. Now the issue is clearly in "something else" (likely in either my global Drupal context or in the rest of my code). So I wonder where and what I could look at, in order to identify what's wrong...

Comment: What exactly is your requirement? I am having a hard time understanding what you are asking?

Comment: What I'm asking? TL;DR; what my title said: why am I getting 404 on Ajax call. But as I precised in my previous comment above, after reading your answer I got pretty sure it didn't come from an erroneous way of doing things, but likely from "something else". So I continued doing some tests, and you can read the following and the end of the story at my new post: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/224886/route-not-registered-likely-hook-menu-not-called.