# Route not registered (likely hook_menu() not called)

Tags: 7, hooks, ajax, navigation

This question follows [this one](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/224809/ajax-call-results-in-404), where I was asking for help about an Ajax call resulting in 404.

I didn't received any answer solving my issue so I continued digging it, then I discovered that it's due to **`hook_menu()` not registering my `MENU_CALLBACK` route in the `menu_router` table**.

Here is my `hook_menu()` implementation:

```
function myModule_menu() {
  return [
    'myModule/ajax' => [
      'page callback'     => '_myModule_ajax_handle',
      'access arguments'  => ['access content'],
      'delivery callback' => '_myModule_ajax_delivery',
      'type'              => MENU_CALLBACK,
    ],
  ];
}
```

I can't see what might be wrong in it.

Then taking advantage of this that my site contains another module of my own, working fine from times, I modified it's `hook_menu()` including *the exact same route*, so it looks like this:

```
function otherModule_menu() {
  return [
    'myModule/ajax' => [
      'page callback'     => '_myModule_ajax_handle',
      'access arguments'  => ['access content'],
      'delivery callback' => '_myModule_ajax_delivery',
      'type'              => MENU_CALLBACK,
    ],
    //... already present routes for "otherModule"
  ];
}
```

This way, the `myModule/ajax` route appears in the `menu_router` table as expected (and so, quite ironically, my Ajax call gets successfull ;).

So the only assumption I can make now is that **`hook_menu()` is not called in the context of `myModule`** (while it is called when in `otherModule`).

Based on that I explored Drupal Answers (and more generally googled) without success: all posts I found either had different issues or obvious errors.

NOTE: indeed my module is active, indeed I'm clearing the cache at each try...

Comment: Can you show your actual code, rather than this with the myModule notation? And is this hook in the .module file?

Comment: @Jaypan Thanks for your interest to my issue. The "myModule notation" (I use to do so because I think it's less confusing for the reader) is the _only_ change: so if you change `myModule` to `bizaudit` and `otherModule` to `mms`, you have the whole real code. And yes, this hook is in the `bizaudit.module`.

Comment: Add a die() to your hook_menu and clear the cache. See if it kills the process. That way you can figure out if the problem is with hook_menu() not being called, or if it's a problem with how you've defined hook_menu(). Looking at it now, it looks fine, but obviously something isn't working.

Comment: @Jaypan I should have reported that I already tried adding `echo '<h1>...';` to my hook, so I was pretty sure it's not called. But I also just tried `die();` as you suggested, and it confirms the same: nothing happens. As you say, "obviously something isn't working" and I desperately look for advices about what else could be checked!

Comment: Adding echo statements to hook_menu() will not result in anything, which is why I said to add the die() statement. So now we've narrowed it down to a problem with your hook_menu() not being called. So you need to ensure that your .module file is named correctly, and that your hook_menu() is named correctly. What is the module key (machine name) for your module, what is the file name and what is the hook_menu() name?

Comment: @Jaypan Wow! Thanks a lot: you made me get it! Because I started editing my question to add complementary information, including the `bizaudit.module`, but replacing a lot of function bodies by `// ...`, and it's how I discovered it. As usual, a dumb gross (while minuscule) detail: the closing bracket `}` of the `bizaudit_help()` function had been moved... just below the entire `bizaudit_menu()` one! So obviously it was as it doesn't exist. Indeed now it works. Again, many thanks. I wonder if you could write an appropriate answer, which I could accept?

Comment: Glad you found it! It's always things like that isn't it.

I don't think I really gave an answer that solved the problem you were having though, so we can just leave it as is.

Comment: @Jaypan Yes "It's always things like that". But after tens of years encountering them, it still stays as annoying. This time, it stuck me about 2 days! Thanks for your time.